# Unable to download jenkins core jar

Tags: build.gradle, jenkins-plugins, gradle-plugin, groovy-grape

I want to download jar for following modules.

**import jenkins.model.Jenkins**

I am trying to download jenkins-core but I am facing issues. It says jar not found.

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.jenkins-ci.main', module='jenkins-core', version='2.9')
])
```

Could anybody please help me out in getting the right jar

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The Jenkins artifacts are not available in Maven Central. You need to add a `@GrabResolver` to point to the Jenkins repository.

```
@GrabResolver(name='jenkins', root='https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/')
@Grab(group='org.jenkins-ci.main', module='jenkins-core', version='2.9')
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the same for build.gradle file. How to do this? Thanks

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? Currently I am fighting the same problem

Comment: any luck anyone ?